# Stuck trying to prove the product property of limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I'm trying to come up with a proof of the statement "if $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=A$ and $\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=B$, then $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)g(x)=AB$".

This is what I've attempted:

Choose some $\epsilon$ > $0$.

Since $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=A$ and $\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=B$, there must exist a $\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ such that:
$$0<|x-p|<\delta_{1}\implies|f(x)-A|<\sqrt{\epsilon}$$
$$0<|x-p|<\delta_{2}\implies|g(x)-B|<\sqrt{\epsilon}$$
Because if $\epsilon>0$, then $\sqrt{\epsilon}>0$ and hence a satisfactory $\delta$ must exist for $\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Let $\delta_{3}=\min(\delta_{1},\delta_{2})$.
Then we must have
$$0<|x-p|<\delta_{3}\implies|f(x)-A|\cdot|g(x)-B|<\epsilon,$$
because $(\sqrt{\epsilon})^2=\epsilon$.

Now I feel as if I must find a way to show that
$$|f(x)-A|\cdot|g(x)-B|=|f(x)g(x)-Ag(x)-Bf(x)+AB|\ge|f(x)g(x)-AB|,$$
but this statement seems to boil down to showing that $-AB\le -Ag(x)-Bf(x)+AB$, which doesn't look like it holds true in the general case. This makes me feel as if I've made some mistake somewhere along the way.

I can't think of any other way to approach this problem, so I've ended up stuck at this point.

Comment: Write $\begin{aligned}|f(x)g(x)-AB|&=|f(x)g(x)-f(x)B+f(x)B-AB|\\&=|f(x)|\cdot|g(x)-B|+|f(x)-A|\cdot|B|.\end{aligned}$

Comment: @Invisible I can understand that the statement given is true but I can't yet figure out how it proves the property. I'm looking at the link, though.

Comment: @MahdiRkioui your method approach in the question won't work: please see my answer.

Comment: I prefer to use slightly different algebraic approach: $$f(x)g(x)-AB=[f(x)-A][g(x)-B] + A[g(x)-B]+B[f(x)-A]$$ If $f(x)-A$ and $g(x)-B$ are small then $f(x)g(x)-AB$ is small.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Could you elaborate on your approach?

Comment: This question is incorrectly marked as a duplicate. Please reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Basically, I don't think your overall proof idea/approach will work because $f(x)g(x)$ *might not* be within a distance of $\varepsilon$ of $AB.$ For example, let $f(x) = x+5,\ g(x) = x+10.\ $ Consider $p=0$.
We have: $A = \lim_{x\to p}f(x)=5$ and $B = \lim_{x\to p}g(x)=10$.

Let $\varepsilon = 1.21.$ Then we could have $\ \delta_1 = 1.1,\ \delta_2 = 1.1,\ $ so that $$0<|x-0|<\delta_{1}\implies|f(x)-5|<\sqrt{\epsilon}=1.1$$
$$0<|x-0|<\delta_{2}\implies|g(x)-10|<\sqrt{\epsilon}=1.1$$

But $ 0 < \vert x - 0 \vert < \min\{ \delta_1, \delta_2 \} =1.1 \not\implies \vert f(x)g(x) - AB \vert = \vert f(x)g(x) - 50 \vert < \varepsilon=1.21.\ $

For example, $x=1$ satisfies $ 0 < \vert x - 0 \vert < 1.1,$ but

$\vert f(1)g(1) - 50 \vert = \vert 66 - 50 \vert = 16 > 1.21.$

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying, but I feel as if I've made completely valid deductions up to the point where I got stuck, clearly I haven't though.. and obviously the property itself isn't wrong, so could you point out where I went wrong with my attempt? What my false assumption was? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't made a false assumption, nor made any incorrect statements. Basically your proof attempt is a few steps in the wrong direction and you need to try something else (i.e. go back to the drawing board).

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused, if I haven't made any mistakes with the attempt why does it "go in the wrong direction"?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it.. the point is that my constructed delta ($\delta_{3}$) *doesn't* satisfy the limit condition for all given $\epsilon$; another delta which does satisfy the condition must exist (otherwise the property wouldn't be true), it just isn't the one I've come up with in my argument. Is this the correct understanding?

Comment: Well, in your proof, you are trying to show that $ 0 < \vert x - p \vert < \delta_3:=\min\{  \delta_1, \delta_2 \} \implies \vert f(x)g(x) - AB \vert$ right? I have shown that this is not necessarily true, and this is due to your poor choice of $\delta_3.$ I have provided a counter-example. Therefore, you can't prove the thing you are trying to prove with your choice of $\delta_3.$ And since $\delta_3$ was defined based on $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, I actually think it is the way you chose all three that made it not work.

Comment: Yes, your previous comment shows you have understood what is going on. When I say poor choice I'm not trying to be condescending; I'm just trying to clarify. Your attempt is actually a very natural first attempt. But it doesn't work, so back to the drawing board...

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks a lot.. I feel as if I understand how proofs like this work a bit better now.

Comment: If you feel like my answer answered your question then feel free to upvote and press the green tick button (which would make my answer "accepted"). I get points and I like points... (I am a simple man)

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$f(x)g(x)-AB=[f(x)-A][g(x)-B]+A[g(x)-B]+B[f(x)-A]$$ Assume $0<\eta<1$ and $|f(x)-A|<\eta,\ |g(x)-B|<\eta.$ Then
$$|f(x)g(x)-AB|<\eta^2+(|A|+|B|)\eta<(1+|A|+|B|)\eta\quad (1)$$
For given $\varepsilon >0$ let $\eta={\varepsilon\over \varepsilon +1+|A|+|B|}.$ Then $0<\eta <1.$ By definition there exists $\delta>0$ such that for $0<|x-p|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-A|<\eta,$ $|g(x)-B|<\eta.$ $^*$

> $^*$ Formally we get $\delta_1$ for $f$ and $\delta_2$ for $g,$ and then we take $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2).$ In general we can choose a common $\delta$ for finitely many limits.

When $0<|x-p|<\delta,$  by applying $(1)$ we get
$$|f(x)g(x)-AB|<(1+|A|+|B|){\varepsilon\over \varepsilon+1+|A|+|B|}<\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

well here is how you can prove it first we know that since $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=A$ and $\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=B$, then $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)g(x)=AB$" we have
$$|g(x)| = |g(x) - B + B| \leq |g(x) - B| + |B|$$
and let  $\epsilon$ = 1 > $0$.
then we have for some delta $$0<|x-p|<\delta_{1}\implies|g(x)-B|<1$$
then by$$0<|x-p|<\delta_{1}\implies|g(x)-B|<1$$ and $$|g(x)| = |g(x) - B + B| \leq |g(x) - B| + |B|$$
we conclude $$0<|x-p|<\delta_{1}\implies|g(x)| < |g(x) - B| + |B| <= 1 + |B| $$
we can conclude similarly that $$0<|x-p|<\delta_{2}\implies|f(x)| < |f(x) - A| + |A| <= 1 + |A| $$
so if we let that $$\epsilon_{1}=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2(1+|B|)}>0$$ and $$\epsilon_{2}=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2(1+|A|)}>0$$
then for some delta3 and delta4 we have
then we have $$0<|x-p|<\delta_{3}\implies|g(x)-B|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2(1+|A|)}$$
and then we have for some delta $$0<|x-p|<\delta_{4}\implies|f(x)-A|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2(1+|B|)}$$
then we let $$\delta:=min({\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3 , \delta_4})$$
we get
$$0<|x-p|<\delta\implies|f(x)g(x) – AB| = |f(x)g(x) +Bf(x) -Bf(x) – AB| \leq |f(x)||g(x)- B| + |B||f(x) – A| 
\leq |f(x)||g(x)- B| + (|B|+1)|f(x) – A|$$
continuing $$0<|x-p|<\delta\implies
|f(x)||g(x)- B| + (|B|+1)|f(x) – A| < (1+|A|) \cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{2(1+|A|)}+(1+|B|) \cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{2(1+|B|)} \le \epsilon $$

hence $$0<|x-p|<\delta\implies|f(x)g(x) – AB| < \epsilon $$

Comment: Because I learned that the approach I was taking is wrong (from the answer I accepted), I'm trying to go through and understand this proof.. thanks for writing it out. Sorry if I didn't make clear what exactly my question was, but this answer is very helpful regardless.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting path to follow  is using the lemma;

If $|x-x_0|<min \bigl(1, \frac{\varepsilon}{2|y_0|+2} \bigr)$ and $|y-y_0|<min \bigl(1, \frac{\varepsilon}{2|x_0|+2} \bigr)$, then $$|xy-x_0y_0|< \varepsilon$$

Proving the lemma can be a fun exercise that introducts one in the reasoning of calculus. Then, the proof for the product of limits is straightforward, just make the necessary substitutions.